# Data Type for Lists

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a table and one of the requirements is that the only option that can be entered are `QLD`, `NSW`, `VIC`, `SA`, `WA`, `NT` and `ACT` (Australian states). What is this datatype and how is written in SQL, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is ENUM, and you should create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE states (
    name VARCHAR(10),
    sta ENUM('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENUM` data type for this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE STATES ( name ENUM('QLD', 'NSW', 'VIC', 'SA', 'WA', 'NT', 'ACT'));
```